# How to use Excel WorksheetFunction.CountA in VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I need to count the number of active cells in column A of Excel.
I can achieve this easily using `worksheetfunction.countA` in Excel VBA, but unable to get the same in VBscript.

Here is my code:

```
Dim objXl , objWorkbook, objSheet ,numofactivecells

Set objXl = createobject("Excel.Application")

set objWorkbook= objXl.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\filename.xlsm")
'change filename

set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objXl.visible = true

objsheet.cells(1,1).select

numofactivecells = objsheet.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

msgbox numofactivecells
```

I need count of cells containing data in column A using VBScript, just like what `CountA` function returns in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim objXl
Dim objWorkbook
Dim objSheet
Dim iActiveCells

Set objXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objXl.Workbooks.open("C:\Temp\test2.xlsx") 'change filename
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objXl.Visible = True

With objSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    iActiveCells = objXl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
End With

MsgBox iActiveCells
```

I explained the problems with your code in your original question.

Comment: Thank you  Étienne Laneville.

Comment: My pleasure @Mahesh! Please accepting the answer by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer. A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.